# Completely close speech recognizer

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I need to use Speech Recognition for file browsing, using command "show numbers". I want Speech Recognizer to start when I open folder browser dialog, and when the browser dialog window closes, I want Speech Recognizer to close. How can I **completely close** speech recognizer using C# in code-behind ?

EDIT:
I have found "ugly" solution for my problem: to kill sapisvr.exe

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to completely close WSR?  It takes a fair amount of time to start up and shut down.  It's possible to make WSR stop listening by CoCreateing the shared recognizer instance (CLSID_SpSharedRecognizer), and then setting the recognizer state to SPRST_INACTIVE.  That's *much* faster.

Answer (score 0):

Your other option is to use an inproc SpeechRecognitionEngine.

Create the engine and load an appropriate grammar (even if it's just the dictation grammar), and then call Recognize() as long as the file browser dialog is open.

Something like this (spitballing, not copied from VS):

```
// This goes in your application initialization code
var engine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
// Set event handlers here...
// Load grammar here...

// This goes in your code where you open the dialog and want
// speech recognition
while (isFileDialogOpen) {
    engine.Recognize(); // It's probably not called 'engine' in your code ;)
}
```

If you only want to do one and only one recognition, you can leave out the while loop and call Recognize bare, but I wouldn't recommend it unless the room is perfectly silent and you don't mutter to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("sapisvr");
foreach (var process in processes)
    {
        process.Kill();
    }
```